# I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after some time running with no problems

Tags: java

In a desktop application created with netbeans I get `NoClassDefFoundError` errors on classes that were being used without problems.

There were no problems when compiling. At runtime, there were no errors for the first hour, or even up to 2 hours, when invoking those same classes. I understand that the error tells us that the definition of some class "disappears" at runtime.

Any JVM parameter that I should check?
Can the responsible for this behavior be the GC? or could it be something else?

While starting the Java application i am using the `-classpath` option:

```bash
java -classpath P:\aplicaciones\App.jar app.Main
```

The exception trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: personal.licencias.entidades.Salida
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Specify classpath, that points to your classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: While starting the Java application iam using the -classpath option

Comment: GUESS: Maybe your app is somehow triggering a "file in use" error on the .jar?  Or perhaps multiple app instances are trying to access the same .jar at the same time? No, unless you're getting an "OutOfMemory" error (or similar), I don't think there are any JVM parameters that might help...

Comment: In what does package does class `personal.licencias.entidades.Salida` belong? Is your `App.jar` a fat (shaded) JAR that contains all its dependencies? Otherwise, `-classpath` should point to other JARs/directories also (as colon-separated entries)